# How to get the returned value from a function displayed into the screen (pyqt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5

The function *genPassword* is going to generate a random password, all I want is getting the value returned from the function and putting it into the screen.

This is the full code.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(553, 600)
        MainWindow.setMouseTracking(False)
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 60, 371, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.generate = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generate.setEnabled(True)
        self.generate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 220, 161, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.generate.setFont(font)
        self.generate.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.generate.setObjectName("generate")
```

Here, I wish to put my password,
Lambda didn't work

```
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 140, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 320, 231, 80))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 553, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Generator"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter the password length"))
        self.generate.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Generate"))
```

Here is the function,
"I want to take the length argument from the **LineEdit** widget"

```
    def genPassword(self, length):
        nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        resources = list(ascii_lowercase) + list(ascii_uppercase) + nums
        result = ""
        for i in range(length):
            result += str(choice(resources))
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase
    from random import choice
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: And *when* should that function be called? By what?

Comment: @musicamante when the button "generate" is clicked

Comment: You're misunderstanding how signals work: they don't get a "return value". If you want to set the text of some QLineEdit using the `genPassword` function, then connect to a function that reads the contents of `self.lineEdit`, calls that `genPassword` function, and set the text on the other line edit with the password. I strongly suggest you to do some careful research about what [signals and slot](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) are and then understand how to implement the logic according to your needs.